# What is the difference between 'content' and 'text'

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using the terrific [Python Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library. I notice that the [fine documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/) has many examples of *how* to do something without explaining the *why*. For instance, both `r.text` and `r.content` are shown as examples of *how* to get the server response. **But where is it explained what these properties do?** For instance, when would I choose one over the other? I see thar `r.text` returns a unicode object *sometimes*, and I suppose that there would be a difference for a non-text response. But where is all this documented? Note that the linked document does state:

> You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:

But then it goes on to show an example of a text response! I can only suppose that the quote above means to say `non-text responses` instead of `non-text requests`, as a non-text request does not make sense in HTTP.

In short, where is the proper *documentation* of the library, as opposed to the (excellent) *tutorial* on the Python Requests site?

Comment: Related: [Should I use .text or .content when parsing a Requests response?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40163323/3357935)

Comment: "In short, where is the proper documentation of the library, as opposed to the (excellent) tutorial on the Python Requests site?" The link on the sidebar that says "API Reference", perhaps?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Thank you. It is quite possible that the Python Requests site was organized differently when the question was asked over eight years ago!

Answer (score 225, accepted):

The `requests.Response` class [documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.Response.text) has more details:

`r.text` is the content of the response in Unicode, and `r.content` is the content of the response in bytes.

Comment: And when would you choose one or the other?

Comment: @multigoodverse: Presumably `r.text` would be preferred for textual responses, such as an HTML or XML document, and `r.content` would be preferred for "binary" filetypes, such as an image or PDF file.

Comment: @dotancohen HTML and XML use declarations in the data to do their own decoding and so they should be fed the raw `r.content`, not the coverted `r.text`.

Comment: More generally, a single response might contain nested or multipart content (like email messages with attachments), and each part might be encoded in different ways. It's impossible to handle such responses without access to the byte stream, but it's a long way from the common case, where you just want correctly-decoded Unicode text.

Comment: Why the python interpreter shows both `r.text` and `r.content` as texts. Why not show `r.content` as text and `r.text` as bits (if that's what it inherently is)?

Answer (score 14):

It seems clear from the documentation is that r.content

```
You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests:

 >>> r.content
```

If you read further down the page it addresses for example an image file

Comment: Thank you. I now see the small `b` preceding the first example with the text "for non-text requests", which means that the object is a bytes object. It is not clear why the bytes is being displayed as text, perhaps that is another Python 'nicety', but it is confusing in this context. Thanks.

Comment: this seems to matter more with python 3.x than python 2.x; using `requests` in python 3 on page.content gives this error:  `if 'rss' in page.content:` --> `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, `text` is nothing, but a sugar-coated version of `content`.

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
response.text == response.content.decode(encoding == response.encoding)
True
```

All internet content is received in the form of bytes. Choose `response.text` for textual responses and use `response.content` for binary files like images or PDF

Comment: Terrific answer, thank you!