# Sending and Receving Zip files with Python Requests

Tags: python, zip, python-requests

I have two REST (Flask) APIs. The first API reads a zip file from the local disk, and returns it in the POST request. The second API calls the first API, and writes the file onto local.

Being a bit ignorant of encodings, I'm running into issues.

```
@app.route('/push/', methods=['POST'])
def push():
    with open('/path/to/zip_file.zip', 'r') as f:
        foo = f.read()
    return foo

@app.route('/pull/', methods=['POST'])
def pull():
    url = 'https://myhost.com/push/'
    r = requests.post(url, verify=False)
    with open(/new/path/to/zip_file.zip', 'w') as f:
        # f.write(r.text)  # this fails with UnicodeEncodeDecode error
        f.write(r.text.encode('utf-8'))  # this doesn't fail, but I can't unzip the resulting file
```

In the second API, I originally tried to `f.write(r.text)`, but this failed with:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 63-64: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried changing it to `f.write(r.text.encode('utf-8'))` after Googling, and while the writing of the file then worked, I received the following error while attempting to `unzip` it in Linux:

```
error [OWBMaster_0.1.zip]:  missing 3112778871 bytes in zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
error [OWBMaster_0.1.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
  zipfile corrupt.
  (please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
  appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Is there a trick to sending zip files over REST with Requests?

Answer (score 0):

Changing `r.text` to `r.content` fixed this:

```
@app.route('/pull/', methods=['POST'])
def pull():
    url = 'https://myhost.com/push/'
    r = requests.post(url, verify=False)
    with open(/new/path/to/zip_file.zip', 'w') as f:
    # f.write(r.content)
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text#) :

> r.text is the content of the response in unicode, and r.content is the content of the response in bytes