# Should I use .text or .content when parsing a Requests response?

Tags: python, python-requests, lxml

I occasionally use `res.content` or `res.text` to parse a response from [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/). In the use cases I have had, it didn't seem to matter which option I used.

What is the main difference in parsing HTML with `.content` or `.text`? For example:

```
import requests 
from lxml import html
res = requests.get(...)
node = html.fromstring(res.content)
```

In the above situation, should I be using `res.content` or `res.text`? What is a good rule of thumb for when to use each?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content):

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
>   encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding
>   guessed by Requests is used when you access `r.text`. You can find out
>   what encoding Requests is using, and change it, using the `r.encoding`
>   property:

```
>>> r.encoding
'utf-8'
>>> r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
```

> If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of
>   `r.encoding` whenever you call `r.text`. You might want to do this in any
>   situation where you can apply special logic to work out what the
>   encoding of the content will be. For example, HTTP and XML have the
>   ability to specify their encoding in their body. In situations like
>   this, you should use `r.content` to find the encoding, and then set
>   `r.encoding`. This will let you use `r.text` with the correct encoding.

So `r.content` is used when the server returns binary data, or bogus encoding headers, to try to find the correct encoding inside a meta tag.

Comment: reading a little further, you'd also use `.content` if the response is in *binary* instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

I think `res.content` and `res.text` are not comparable and which one you should use depends on your use case. Use `res.text` for textual responses and use `res.content` for binary files like images or PDF.

All internet content is received in the form of bytes. To prevent converting it to Unicode format, **Requests** provides `text` attribute. Assume `text` as a sugar-coated version of `content`.

```
import requests
res = requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get")
res.text == res.content.decode(encoding == res.encoding)
True
```