# How to identify which HTML tags or classes to specify when scraping from a webpage?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the news links (highlighted in the screenshot below) in a website:

[image]

When I `inspect` the page, I see that the links I want are contained in the class `col-sm-5` under the tag `h5`. I want to scrape all 4 links (with tag `li`) in that div class, `col-sm-5`. So, I wrote the following code to extract the links:

```
import requests 
page = requests.get("http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News","html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
li_box = soup.find('h5', attrs={'class': 'col_sm_5'})
print(li_box)
```

But the output I get is `none`; it can't find the tag, I assume. So, my question is, how do I specify the class, tag or other information required to find and extract the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access element which don't exists in HTML of page.

```
li_box = soup.find('h5', attrs={'class': 'col_sm_5'})
```

in this line you are trying to get h5 tag with class 'col_sm_5' which don't exists in HTML of page. In HTML there exits only 'div' with class 'col-sm-5'.

Now Solution. Most easy way to do this is to use select() of beautifulSoup.

```
>>> page = requests.get("http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News","html.parser")
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
>>> aa = soup.select("div.col-sm-5 ul.list-default li h5 a")
>>> for a in aa:
...     print(a.attrs['href'])
...
/Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law
/Mock-News-Article/id/42946/Type/eDaily/India-M-A-deals-brewing-in-insurance-sector
/Mock-News-Article/id/42947/Type/eDaily/China-Online-insurance-premiums-soar-31-in-1Q2018
/Mock-News-Article/id/42948/Type/eDaily/South-Korea-Courts-increasingly-see- 65-as-retirement-age
>>>
```

soup.select will find all a tags within h5 within li within div with class col-sm-5

Then iterate through all elements and get required attr which in your case is href.

Answer (score 1):

`requests.get()` do not need `"html.parser"`, which is for beautifulsoup.

Also, the class name is `col-sm-5` not `col_sm_5`.

It's better to use response `content` instead of `text`. (Maybe not true, see comments)

You could use css selector as below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www3.asiainsurancereview.com/News")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
li_box = soup.select('div.col-sm-5 > ul > li > h5 > a')
for link in li_box:
    print(link['href'])
```

Output:

```
/Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law
/Mock-News-Article/id/42946/Type/eDaily/India-M-A-deals-brewing-in-insurance-sector
/Mock-News-Article/id/42947/Type/eDaily/China-Online-insurance-premiums-soar-31-in-1Q2018
/Mock-News-Article/id/42948/Type/eDaily/South-Korea-Courts-increasingly-see-65-as-retirement-age
```

Comment: *It's better to use response `content` instead of `text`* - Why? It's not. Have a look at questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163323/should-i-use-text-or-content-when-parsing-a-requests-response/40163370). While parsing HTML use `.text.` and while downloading files or related stuff (when you need the data in binary) use `.content`. So, it's better to use `text` here.

Answer (score 0):

> there is no class exist for h5 tag

Try out this,

```
select_div = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col-sm-5'})
result = []
for each_div in select_div:
    links = each_div.findAll('a');
    for each_tag in links:
        link = each_tag.attrs['href']       
        result.append(str(link))

print(result)
```

Output will be list of url

> ['/Mock-News-Article/id/42945/Type/eDaily/New-Zealand-Govt-starts-public-consultation-phase-of-review-of-insurance-law', '/Mock-News-Article/id/42946/Type/eDaily/India-M-A-deals-brewing-in-insurance-sector', '/Mock-News-Article/id/42947/Type/eDaily/China-Online-insurance-premiums-soar-31-in-1Q2018', '/Mock-News-Article/id/42948/Type/eDaily/South-Korea-Courts-increasingly-see-65-as-retirement-age']