# How to fix error "Object of type bites is not JSON serializable" with API, JSON, and Python

Tags: python, json, encoding

Oddly enough, this same code worked pretty much exactly as I wanted it to on my MacBook Pro, but now that I'm trying to do the same thing on Windows with my work computer, it's having a bit of trouble. Perhaps that will shed light on the issue?

Anyway, here's the line of code that's giving me trouble:

```
with open('PATH', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(surveyDetails.content, outfile).encode('utf8')
```

You can see that I filled it to the brim with attempts to encode it as utf-8. I didn't need do this on my Mac, but whatever. However, I'm still getting the same error, when most similar posts I've read have said that this is the solution. I'm not sure what else to try--is there another way to encode this that should work better?

Comment: Why would you `encode()` `json.dump()`? It returns nothing for you to `encode()` with.  Did you mean to `json.dump(surveyDetails.content.decode('utf-8'), outfile)` instead? Also it would be more helpful if you post the full traceback and relevant code as a [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to encode anything. The problem is that the object you're trying to dump is *already* encoded into a `bytes` object, and JSON doesn't know what to do with those.

If `surveyDetails.content` itself is a `bytes` object, decode it before passing:

```
json.dump(surveyDetails.content.decode('utf-8'), outfile)
```

If `surveyDetails.content` is a dict, list, or other object that *contains* one or more `bytes` object, you'll need to go through and decode any `bytes` objects in it before dumping it.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Evidently, I need to gain a better understanding of encoding vs decoding etc.

Comment: @jeepersmcface Accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163323/should-i-use-text-or-content-when-parsing-a-requests-response/40163370 summarises differences between response.text, response.content, and when to use encodings. Hope that helps.