# Regex not matching text scraped with soup.get_text()

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-re

The code below works until:

```
print(salary_range)
```

This is the code:

```
url = "https://nofluffjobs.com/pl/job/c-c-junior-software-developer-vesoftx-wroclaw-n6bgtv5f"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
salaries = soup.find_all("h4", class_="tw-mb-0")
markup2 = str(salaries[0])
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(salaries[0]), 'html.parser')

salary_range = soup2.get_text().strip()
print(salary_range) #output: "10 000  – 16 000  PLN"

# error on line below
bottom_salary = re.search(r"^(\d{0,2} ?\d{3})", salary_range).group(1)
print(bottom_salary)

bottom_salary_int = re.sub(" ", "", bottom_salary)
print(bottom_salary_int)
```

Why doesn't `re.search()` find any match? I've tried many other regular expressions, but it never finds a match and I always get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: @MichaelM. Thanks, I'm new to this.  Answer checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the character you think is a space is not actually a space, it is a [*non-breaking space*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). Despite looking the same, they are completely different characters. It has the same function of a regular space, but it doesn't count for line wrapping purposes. See this small diagram:

```
10 000  – 16 000  PLN
  ^   ^^
 NBSP SP  ... same deal here
```

To match the non-breaking space instead, specify its hex value, `0xA0`. Like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

url = "https://nofluffjobs.com/pl/job/c-c-junior-software-developer-vesoftx-wroclaw-n6bgtv5f"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, "html.parser")
salaries = soup.find_all("h4", class_="tw-mb-0")
markup2 = str(salaries[0])
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(str(salaries[0]), 'html.parser')

salary_range = soup2.get_text().strip()
print(salary_range)

bottom_salary = re.search(r"^(\d{0,2}\xa0?\d{3})", salary_range).group(1)
print(bottom_salary)

bottom_salary_int = re.sub(" ", "", bottom_salary)
print(bottom_salary_int)
```

If you're trying to match a space, but the regular space character doesn't match, then it might be a NBSP instead. You can also tell by the website's source code if it uses `&nbsp;` instead of a regular space to encode a NBSP.

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Indeed, the source code contains '&nbsp;'. I wonder though, why your code works and this doesn;t: '"^(\d{0,2}\xa0?\d{3}).+$"'. Why does it need to be separated?

Comment: `r"^(\d{0,2}\xa0?\d{3}).+$"` is also working, but you have to ensure that you use a stripped string here cause your pattern uses `^` so it would fail, if you use a string with leading characters that are not digits. However, try to simplify your pattern, if it is not explicitly required.

Comment: @MikołajPrzygoda Sorry, that was a small typo. As HedgeHog pointed out, it works without separating the strings too. I've edited my answer to update that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition, if you prefer a less explicit definition of a character (*non-breaking space*), simply change the pattern to `(\d+.\d+)` or `(\d+\s\d+)` to get your group, also `^` is not needed in this specific case:

`.` Matches any character.

```
re.search(r"(\d+.\d+)", e.get_text()).group(1)
```

`\s` Matches any space, tab or newline character.

```
re.search(r"(\d+\s\d+)", e.get_text()).group(1)
```

To fix the spacing simply `split()` and `join()`:

```
''.join(re.search(r"(\d+.\d+)", e.get_text()).group(1).split())
```

##### Example

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://nofluffjobs.com/pl/job/c-c-junior-software-developer-vesoftx-wroclaw-n6bgtv5f"
reqs = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.content)
for e in soup.find_all("h4", class_="tw-mb-0"):
    print(''.join(re.search(r"(\d+.\d+)", e.get_text()).group(1).split()))
```

##### Output

```
10000
9000
```

Comment: Yes, as a beginner I am still learning to make my code more concise. Thanks! One more question: As far as I understand, `requests.content` method returns the content in bytes. Why is it better to use it instead of `requests.text`?

Comment: In this context both are fine in my opinion, cause it do not effect behavior - May take a short read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40163370/14460824 think this is to the point.