# Beautifulsoup4 error selecting multiple attrs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new in bs4 and I'm trying to scraping some information about amazon products for a university assignment, in particular I'm trying to extract product categories from html page. I tried to extract it in this way, but i get a void array.

I need to extract: Grocery & Gourmet Food, Candy & Chocolate, Jelly Beans & Gummy Candy, Licorice

This is the part of the web page I would like to scrape, but I don't know how to access to this:

```
<div id="wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container" class="a-section a-spacing-none a-padding-medium breadcrumb-fst-exp-1 fst-breadcrumb-feature">
    <ul class="a-unordered-list a-horizontal a-size-small">
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/grocery-breakfast-foods-snacks-organic/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_1?ie=UTF8&node=16310101">
                Grocery & Gourmet Food
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/Candy-Chocolate/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_2?ie=UTF8&node=16322461">
                Candy & Chocolate
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_3?ie=UTF8&node=17369013011">
                Jelly Beans & Gummy Candy
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/Licorice-Candy/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_4?ie=UTF8&node=16322521">
                Licorice
            </a>
         </span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/" + 'B001GVISJM'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for divtag in soup.find_all("div", attr={"id" : "wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container"}):
    print(divtag)
```

Comment: So something like: `[a.text.strip() for a in soup.select('div#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container ul li span a')]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like below. For findind by id, you can pass it as function argument instead of passing it inside `attrs`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

t = '''
<div id="wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container" class="a-section a-spacing-none a-padding-medium breadcrumb-fst-exp-1 fst-breadcrumb-feature">
    <ul class="a-unordered-list a-horizontal a-size-small">
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/grocery-breakfast-foods-snacks-organic/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_1?ie=UTF8&node=16310101">
                Grocery & Gourmet Food
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/Candy-Chocolate/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_2?ie=UTF8&node=16322461">
                Candy & Chocolate
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_3?ie=UTF8&node=17369013011">
                Jelly Beans & Gummy Candy
            </a>
         </span></li>
         <li><span class="a-list-item">
            <a class="a-link-normal" href="/Licorice-Candy/b/ref=dp_bc_aui_T1_4?ie=UTF8&node=16322521">
                Licorice
            </a>
         </span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')
for divtag in soup.find_all(id="wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container"):
    for d in divtag.find_all(attrs={'class': 'a-link-normal'}):
        print(d.get_text().strip())
```

Output:

```
Grocery & Gourmet Food
Candy & Chocolate
Jelly Beans & Gummy Candy
Licorice
```

Comment: Probably easier (and arguably more readable) to use `.select(...)` here as per my comment on the Q...

Comment: it works if i consider this specific html, but when i try to scrape the entire html page from amazon it doesn't work =( any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Short and fast selector (combining id for the breadcrumb and then type selector of `a` for the links.

```
categories = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_feature_div a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in soup.find('div', id='wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container').find('ul').find_all('li', class_=None):
    text = i.find('a').text.strip()
    print(text)
```

or

```
for i in soup.select('#wayfinding-breadcrumbs_container a'):
    text = i.text.strip()
    print(text)
```

The actual amazon page has another div that you aren't accounting for. The structure is:

```
<div>
<div> <--- missing in your post
<ul>
<li>
...
```

On a side note: Amazon is notoriously finicky about scraping. Without using timers, proxies, cookies, and redundancy loops- your scraper will be very inconsistent.

Comment: How can i correctly set timers, proxies, cookies and other things i need , in python?

Comment: Furthermore should i pass r.text or r.content as Beautifulsoup argument, what's the difference?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text

text for html/xml documents and content for binary types like an image or pdf file

Comment: @StefanoSacco without a large set of proxies I think the easiest way is to use a service like proxycrawl. You send the request to their service and you pay per request, but they only charge you for successful requests. Obviously if this is just a school project it doesn't make sense to do this.

For everything else the best way is to use a scraping framework like Scrapy. There is a bit of a learning curve, but it is designed specifically to do this. It can handle headers, variable timing delays (AUTOTHROTTLE=True in settings) which I've found to be the best measure against captchas.