# How to fix gibberish to Hebrew strings in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to automate an email sending service, which sends a person's bus station to his mail.

In order to do so I need to pull some data from a Hebrew website,
but all I get is a file with gibberish in it.

I have tried encoding to `utf8`, but all I get is more gibberish.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://yit.maya-tour.co.il/yit-pass/Drop_Report.aspx?client_code=2660&coordinator_code=2669'
html = requests.get(url).content
df_list = pd.read_html(html)
df = df_list[-1]
print(df)
df.to_csv('my data.csv')
```

I expected for the following:

> רשימת פיזורים
>
> שם הנהג   סוג הרכב    הערות   תאור    שעה
>
> מוניות הקניון מונית   A35 פיזור-שדרות 06:30

but got:

```
               ×©× ×× ×× ×¡×× ××¨××  ...               ×ª×××¨ ×©×¢×
0  ××× ×××ª ××§× ×××      ××× ××ª  ...  ×¤××××¨-×©××¨××ª  06:30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A response object's `.content` property gives you the data in bytes, try doing `.text` instead:

`html = requests.get(url).text`

More detail here:
[What is the difference between 'content' and 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text)