# How to pick a string from a list and convert it to a list - Python

Tags: python, list, random, python-requests

What i want to do is make a hang man game, this is the first phase.
I want to pick a word from that online list of words.

I print it to verify it's working.

Till the print line every thing works as intended.

After that there is 2 things:

1- The word is printed like this:b'covered'

Why is there a b? and How to remove it?

2- When i guess a letter it always give false even if the letter is in the word, like this:

b'covered'

Guess a letter: o

False

False

False

False

False

False

False

How can I fix that ?

```
import requests
import random
word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"
rand=random.randint(0,10000)
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
pick=WORDS[rand]
pick_as_list=list(pick)
print(pick)
user=input("Guess a letter: ")
for letter in pick_as_list:
    if user == letter:
        print("Right")
    elif user != letter:
        print("False")
```

This code works fine with a given a list not one imported from a site:

```
rand=random.randint(0,2)
word_list = ["aardvark", "baboon", "camel"]
pick=word_list[rand]
pick_as_list=list(pick)
user=input("Guess a letter: ")
for letter in pick_as_list:
    if user == letter:
        print("Right")
    elif user != letter:
        print("False")
```

I want to make it work but with a huge list of words.

Comment: `requests` reads the page as binary bytes, because it doesn't know that it contains words.  Do `WORDS = response.content.decode().splitlines()` to convert it to Unicode.  That's probably the root of your guess problem as well, because `'x'` is not equal to `b'x'`.

Comment: Another comment is you dont have to convert a str to a list. A str is a list of characters. So you can iterate and index a string the same as you would a list.

Comment: Thanks for telling me that. I didn't know it.

Comment: Instead of `response.content` use `response.text`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between 'content' and 'text'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011357/what-is-the-difference-between-content-and-text)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Tim Roberts.

`requests` reads the page as binary bytes, because it doesn't know that it contains words. Do `WORDS = response.content.decode().splitlines()` to convert it to Unicode. That's probably the root of your guess problem as well, because `'x'` is not equal to `b'x'`

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. What you are seeing with the `b''` type string is binary. You have to call the `decode()` method of the binary to convert to ascii or what-have-you. You can also get the `response.text` instead of `response.content` to not have to tangle with binary at all.
2. Prompt for `user` input inside the loop. Otherwise you only prompt once and then loop through each letter in your `pick`.
3. To see if the guessed a letter correctly you want to see if that letter is in their `pick` otherwise you are just comparing the user input letter to whichever `letter` you are on in your iteration, meaning your user would have to spell the word in order to win. So `if user in pick_a_list`

---

```
import requests
import random
word_site = "https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000"
rand=random.randint(0,10000)
response = requests.get(word_site)
WORDS = response.content.splitlines()
pick=WORDS[rand].decode('ascii')
pick_as_list=list(pick)
print(pick)
for letter in pick_as_list:
    user=input("Guess a letter: ")
    
    #You may find it helpful to print some variables in this loop to see what's going on. 
    #print(user, pick_as_list)
    if user in pick_as_list:
        print("Right")
    elif user != letter:
        print("False")
```

Obviously still a lot of spit-and-polish needed to make this a hangman game, but this should get you past the issues are seeing now.